# How to control master volume in linux/c++?

Tags: c++, linux, audio, gnome, volume

Specifically, I'm using Fedora 13 but I believe the code would be similar across any Gnome-ish flavor of Linux.  I just need to be able to adjust the master volume using C++, and accomplish the exact same effect as if I had moved the slider up and down on the speaker icon in the "system tray."  What's the best and easiest way to code this?

Comment: `but I believe the code would be similar across any Gnome-ish flavor of Linux` You'd be surprised.

Comment: You haven't seen Linux Audio Jungle yet I guess, http://blogs.adobe.com/penguinswf/2007/05/welcome_to_the_jungle.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to use the [Alsa library](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___simple_mixer.html). Or you could cheat and subprocess the amixer program.

Comment: Can you or anyone please provide a little more guidance on using the linked Alsa library to adjust the master volume?

Comment: From command line you can do `amixer set Master 1.0dB+` to increase volume and `amixer set Master 1.0dB-` to decrease it. I guess you can translate it into sequence of API calls to achieve your goals (i.e. select device, channel, type of adjustment (set of decrement/increment)).
It is very convinient to  bind these commands on `Super+Up`, `Super+Down` keys to control volume from keyboard anywhere you like.